# How to get a clear output of html2text in python?

Tags: python

I have the following python program:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import html2text

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.stern.de/")
page_source = html.read()

h = html2text.HTML2Text()
h.ignore_links = True
h.ignore_images = True

text = h.handle(str(page_source))

print (text)
```

The output is:

```
\n \n\n

    * \n Anmelden
\n\n

    * \n 

Sie haben noch keinen Account?

\n Kostenlos neu registrieren

\n \n

\n
```

How can I filter out the "\n"?

I tried it for example this way and it don't work:

```
wordList = text.split()

for word in wordList:
    if word != "\n":
        print (word)
```

This is the output after splitting:

```
\n\n
*
\n
Anmelden
\n\n
*
\n
Sie
haben
noch
keinen
Account?
\n
Kostenlos
neu
registrieren
\n
\n
\n
```

So my check did not work. How can I check for the \n newline symbol?

Comment: That's the newline character. It will "go away" (rather, properly break the line instead of appearing as '\n') if you print it. Do you really _want_ all the text run together on one line?

Comment: I want each word seperated as an array. If I don't ignore it \n is recognised as a word

Comment: `text.split()` will count `\n` as whitespace

Comment: This is not your real code or there's something you're not telling us. If you copy the text you have into a string and call split on it, you get: `['*',

 'Anmelden',

 '*',

 'Sie',

 'haben',

 'noch',

 'keinen',

 'Account?',

 'Kostenlos',

 'neu',

 'registrieren']`

Comment: It is the actual code. You can copy and run it. I think it is working for you because you copied it and the one symbol "\n" is translated into two symbols \+n and then it is recognised

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved it this way, because I debugged it and found that \n is in debug mode \n.

```
text = text.replace('\\n', '')
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try with `replace`?

```
text.replace('\n', '')
```